# How to call getFragmentManager from base adapter in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

In my app i am having the list view populated using the `base adapter` inside `fragment class`.Here i want to call the another fragment by clicking the button from base adapter i did some thing but it was showing the `nullpointer exception` because of fragment manager
can any one tell me how to call `fragment manager` from `base adapter` in android
this is the code i have inside my `base adapter`

```
package com.adapter.sales;

import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.lotus.com.androidmis.R;
import android.lotus.com.androidmis.Sales;
import android.lotus.com.androidmis.Salesteam;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.lotus.mis.modle.UserDetails;


public class Emp_Spinner_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<UserDetails> objects;
    String Flaglist = "3";
    FragmentManager fragment;

    public Emp_Spinner_Adapter(Context context, int resource,
            List<UserDetails> objects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View Row = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.layout_adapter_sales_team_members, null);


        TextView txt_item = (TextView) Row.findViewById(R.id.txt_item);
        ImageView img_count = (ImageView) Row.findViewById(R.id.img_count);
        ImageView details_sales = (ImageView)Row.findViewById(R.id.img_details_sales);
        final UserDetails UserDetails_item = (UserDetails) objects
                .get(position);

        txt_item.setText("  " + UserDetails_item.getUserName());

        final int temp_count = Integer
                .valueOf(UserDetails_item.GetWorkStatus());
        if (temp_count > 0) {
            img_count.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_lotus_team);
            img_count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String username = UserDetails_item.getUserName();

                    //Intent i = new Intent(context, Sales.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("key_username",
                            UserDetails_item.getUserName());
                    bundle.putString("key_userid", UserDetails_item.getUserID());
                    bundle.putString("report_username", Salesteam.txt_levels
                            .getText().toString());
                    bundle.putString("key_FlagList", Flaglist);
                    Salesteam sales_team = new Salesteam();
                    sales_team.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = fragment.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, sales_team).commit();

                    //i.putExtras(bundle);
                    //context.startActivity(i);

                }
            });

        }

        details_sales.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                        Sales.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("key_username", UserDetails_item.getUserName());
                bundle.putString("key_userid", UserDetails_item.getUserID());
                bundle.putString("report_username", Salesteam.txt_levels.getText().toString());
                bundle.putString("key_FlagList", Flaglist);
                Sales sales_fragment = new Sales();
                sales_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = fragment.beginTransaction();
                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, sales_fragment).commit();
                // bundle.putString("report_username", TempUser.getUserName());
                // bundle.putString("report_user_id", TempUser.getUserID());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        if (position % 2 == 1) {
            Row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        } else {
            Row.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        }
        img_count.setAlpha(255);

        txt_item.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);

        return Row;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of the Emp_Spinner_Adapter constructor, pass another FragmentManager variable in it and initialise the predefined fragmentmanager variable with it as:

```
 public Emp_Spinner_Adapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<UserDetails> objects,FragmentManager manager ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.fragment=manager;

}
```

Now in the MainActivity while calling the Emp_Spinner_Adapter, create a FragmentManager variable in the activity and initialise it and then pass it in the object.Hope that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your activity reference in Adapter's constructor

```
Activity mActivity;

 public Emp_Spinner_Adapter(Activity context, int resource,
            List<UserDetails> objects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
this.mActivity= context;

    }
```

and then use it as

```
mActivity.getFragmentManager();
```

Comment: But here i am calling this adapter also from the fragment @praveen Sharma

Comment: So pass your activity instance simple.

Comment: Sorry to ask u like this what is here `Activity` instance means instance of calling fragment or to be called fragment @ praveen Sharma can u help me with the code please

Comment: inside your `Fragment class` where you are calling `BaseAdapter `constructor just use `getActivity()` method to get `Activity instance`;

Comment: But when i am writing that showing `incompatible types` error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move fragment inside adapter than use this snippets

```
img_count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    YourFragment fragment= new YourFragment ();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("Id", "1");
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager =  ((Activity) mContext).getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
  });
```

Comment: What should i pass here in `Activity`

Comment: I didnt get it, you have to write this code in click listener inside base adapter

Comment: I wrote this but it was showing to convert them to android.app.fragmentmanager

Comment: What type of fragment you are using app.fragment or v4.fragment?

Comment: try getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager